# footer div under another div with height:100% and scroll, with CSS

Tags: css

i have some div with `height:100%`, that have within this 3 divs: header, main, footer.

*( here you can see an exemple: http://i61.tinypic.com/28mjpya.jpg )*

in the 'main' div, i have a scroll, and i need this to be with `height:100%`

but when i do `height:100%` to the 'main' div, i cant see the 'footer' div.

and if i will do the 'footer' div with `position:absulute; bottom:0px;` it will hide my scroll bar of the 'main' div.

how can i solve this problem?

---

*this is my source:* http://jsfiddle.net/8YEJY/

```
<div style='position:fixed; left:0px; width:200px; height:100%;'>
    <div id='hearer' style='width:100%; height:40px; background-color:lime;'>
        aaa
    </div>
    <div id='main' style='width:100%; height:100%; overflow:scroll; background-color:green;'>
        bbb
    </div>
    <div id='footer' style='width:100%; height:30px; background-color:pink;'>
        ccc
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you know the width just take some off the footer to allow for the scrollbar to been seen. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8YEJY/).. Is this not what you want..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position:absolute;` on the `#main` and `#footer` like this :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/QAfNG/)**

*What I did to your code :*

- removed the inline styles and put them in a sperate stylesheet. This makes the code cleaner and inline styles are not recommended.
- removed `position:fixed;` on the first container, it isn't needed for your layout.
- removed unecessary css properties
- changed the tags to *HTML 5* tags
- set `html,body{height:100%;margin:0;}` so the `#wrap` container can expand to the height of the window with `height:100%;` and `position:relative;`.

*HTML :*

```
<div id="wrap">
    <header>aaa</header>
    <main>bbb</main>
    <footer>ccc</footer>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
#wrap {
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    height:40px;
    background-color:lime;
}
#main {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:40px;
    bottom:30px;
    overflow:scroll;
    background-color:green;
}
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    height:30px;
    background-color:pink;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making the content div scroll you could place your header and footer fixed an let the body scroll:

HTML:

```
<div id="header">header</div>

<div id="content">content</div>

<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%; /* needs to be set */
}

#header, #footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px; /* needs to be a fixed width! */
    position: fixed;
    top 0;
    background: lightgreen;
}
#footer {
    bottom: 0;
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* include the padding in the height */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

And a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/mw3Tc/).

[EDIT based on your comment]

Change `#content` to:

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

Check the [**updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/mw3Tc/1/).

Note: instead of fixed positioning, you could also place `#header`, `#content` and `#footer` absolute, check this link. Result is the same though.

Comment: thanks, but its not what i need, i need the scroll bar just in the 'main' div.

Answer (score 0):

just add position:absolute and some bottom margin,I have added as bottom:0%;

This one works fine

```
<div style='position:fixed; left:0px; width:200px; height:100%;'>
    <div id='hearer' style='width:100%; height:40px; background-color:lime;'>
        aaa
    </div>
    <div id='main' style='width:100%; height:100%; overflow:scroll; background-color:green;'>
        bbb
    </div>
    <div id='footer' style='width:100%; height:30px; background-color:pink;position:absolute;bottom:1%;'>
        ccc
    </div>
</div>
```